# Can I start the Calendar Control for asp.NET to be a future date?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar, controls

I need to have the Calendar Control start 36 hours after the current date. How would I do that?

I have a form that requires that the future date has to be at least 36 hours from the current date in the order for the workers involved to be able to complete the task.

EDIT: Thanks everyone for helping with my question. I've created a solution that will allow me to check values and keep the form from processing:

```
Protected Sub calPickupDate_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles calPickupDate.SelectionChanged
        If calPickupDate.SelectedDate < Today.AddHours(36) Then
            ASPNET_MsgBox("You must leave at least 36 hours for procesing of your order.")
            txtPickupDate.Text = ""
        Else
            txtPickupDate.Text = calPickupDate.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        End If
    End Sub
```

So, how do I close out the question?

Comment: I should clarify my question. Yes I am talking of the date picker control. I have a text box, disabled, with today's date. I would like for the date of the date picker to start at 36 hours after the date in the text box. There is a process that requires the person filling the form to wait at least that amount of time before the requested product is ready.

Comment: You should give credit for this answer to milter.  His answer is exactly what you were asking for, even if you decided to go with server side validation in the end.

Comment: @therealmitchconnors - You're right. It was the basis for my solution, which works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    Dim DateTimePicker As New DateTimePicker
    DateTimePicker.MinDate = Date.Now.AddHours(36)
    DateTimePicker.Value = Date.Now.AddHours(36)
```

Answer (score 4):

add below code on your form load.

```
calPickupDate.MinDate = Date.Now.AddHours(36)
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean a date picker type of "calendar" and not a calendar. If so, you are dealing with a data validation issue.

There are different ways to validate the input. The quickest is server side only. If the user picks the wrong date, you tell him and he can pick ad nauseum until he gets a clue. Not the best UI, but it works.

Since the data ends up in a textbox, you can set javaScript on the textbox to remove wrong dates and show an "error" label with a message like "date/time must be X". If you can use AJAX, there are some pretty neat samples [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx).